# Problema para validar dentro del for

Tags: c

Quiero validar los datos para que al ingresar un numero impar aparezca un cartel de advertencia. Pero no logro que esa validación deje de ser tomada como una vuelta del for.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int array[6];
    
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
        printf ("Ingresar numeros pares\n");
        scanf("%d", & array[i]);
        while (array[i] %2!=0){
        printf("Solo numeros pares\n");
    
        break;
    
        }
    
    }
        printf ("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
        printf("%d\n",  array[i]);
}
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Has probado a añadir un `i--;` dentro del while y antes del break? De esa manera, el índice se altera en -1, y en la siguiente iteración del foro se vuelve a incrementar (con lo que no ocupas esa iteración.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No me parece buena idea tu ciclo `while` dentro del `for` para validar (¿No sería mejor un if sobre algún input?); lo mismo que antes de validar, asignar lo ingresado al array; de lo contrario: ¿Para qué te sirve querer validar algo que ya ingresaste?

Te propongo este nuevo código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define sizeofarray(_array) ( sizeof(_array)/sizeof(_array[0]) )
//|_____________________________________________________________|
//                             |
//             Esta es una estrategia tipica
//             para obtener la longitud de un
//             array

int main() {
    int array[6];
    int input;
    int contador = 0; 

    printf("Ingresar numeros pares: ");
    
    while (contador < sizeofarray(array)) {
    
        scanf("%i", &input);  //  Asignamos la entrada a la variable "input"
                              //                 |
        if (input % 2 != 0) { //<----------------| para luego validar aca
            printf("Solo numeros pares\n");  //  |
            printf("Continua ingresando: "); //  |
        } //                                     |
        else { //                                |     
            printf("Continua ingresando: "); //  |                                   
            array[contador]=input; //<-----------| y si se valido, entonces                          
            contador++; //                         se asigna al array
        }
    }

    printf ("\n");
    printf ("Elementos ingresados: \n");

    for(int i=0; i < sizeofarray(array); i++) {
        printf("%i\n",  array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Que al ejecutarlo, devuelve lo siguiente:

```
$ gcc -o validador_so validador_so.c && ./validador_so
Ingresar numeros pares: 3
Solo numeros pares
Continua ingresando: 6
Continua ingresando: 2
Continua ingresando: 1
Solo numeros pares
Continua ingresando: 123
Solo numeros pares
Continua ingresando: 24
Continua ingresando: 24
Continua ingresando: 24
Continua ingresando: 2
Continua ingresando:
Elementos ingresados:
6
2
24
24
24
2
```

Answer (score 0):

El break lo que hace es que se sale del ciclo while y continua el for, ocupas un condicional if

```
for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
    printf ("Ingresar numeros pares\n");
    scanf("%d", & array[i]);

    if(array[i] %2!=0){
        printf("Solo numeros pares\n");
        break;
    }

}
```

Haciendo de este modo al final te va a imprimir el arreglo pero con "basura". puedes agregar una bandera para que al final imprimas o no dependiendo si fue correcto.

```
int main(){
int array[6];
bool flag = false;

for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
    printf ("Ingresar numeros pares\n");
    scanf("%d", & array[i]);

    if(array[i] %2!=0){
        printf("Solo numeros pares\n");
        break;
    }
    flag =true;

}
if(flag==true){
    printf ("\n");

    for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
        printf("%d\n",  array[i]);
    }
}
return 0;
```

}